# Disabling and enabling a button during postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to disable a button and change its text while doing a postback and then i want to change the text back to normal when postback is complete.

```
<asp:Button ID="b_Generate" runat="server" onclick="b_Generate_Click" OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Please Wait...';" 
Text="Generate PPT"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
style="z-index: 1; left: 05px; top: 50px; position: absolute; width: 110px;" 
BorderStyle="Ridge" Font-Bold="True" 
ToolTip="click here" />
```

With the above code i'm able to disable the button and change the text before post back starts but i'm not sure how to enable the button once again and change the text back to the previous one once post back is complete.

Comment: Normally the button should get it's old value after postback since the page is again submitted to the client. The server didn't even mention that the client has changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually add this method to my BasePage for reuse. Your code does not handle validations

```
/// <summary>
///  Avoid multiple submit
/// </summary>
/// <param name="button">The button.</param>
/// <param name="text">text displayed on button</param>
public void AvoidMultipleSubmit(Button button,string text="wait..." )
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(), "ServerForm", "if(this.submitted) return false; this.submitted = true;");
    button.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate)=='function' && !Page_ClientValidate()){{return true;}}this.value='{1}';this.disabled=true;{0}",
        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(button, string.Empty),text));
}
```

Comment: This causes the autocomplet functionality in IE to malfunction !

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me this code is run only during postback... why would you need autocomplete during postback??

Comment: Not during the postback. After it, the autocomplete does not work anymore.

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me browser autocomplete or an external autocomplete plugin

Comment: Browser autocomplete. Default from IE

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me never experienced it. do you have a test page?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `return true`.

```
<asp:Button ID="b_Generate" runat="server" onclick="b_Generate_Click" 
            OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Please Wait...'; return true;" 
            Text="Generate PPT"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
            style="z-index: 1; left: 05px; top: 50px; position: absolute; width: 110px;" 
            BorderStyle="Ridge" Font-Bold="True" 
            ToolTip="click here"
/>
```

Comment: Hey Hii Thanks for your answer but once i add return as true, button doesn't call the b_Generate_Click onclick method.